# How to tell if an option of type string is specified or not in Cement2

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am using python's Cement2 library to parse command line argument:

```
app.args.add_argument('-f', '--foo', action='store', metavar='STR',
                      help='the notorious foo option')
```

The full code example could be found here: http://cement.readthedocs.org/en/1.9.2/dev/quickstart/#getting-warmer

So here the *-f* is a string option, and what I want is it could tell the difference of:

1. -f is not provided
2. -f
3. -f "foo"

But here I can't tell the difference between 1 and 2 --- the value captured are all `arg.foo == None`.

Any idea on how to differentiate the first 2 cases?

Thanks.